# What is the formula behind the Empirical Rule?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

I am trying to find the formula for the Empirical Rule, but all I can find are examples of how to use the rule.  For example, I know that 68% of my data will fall within one standard deviation of the mean.  Given a mean and a standard deviation, I can calculate the range within my data set.  What I am looking for is the source of the 68%, 95%, and 99.7%.  For example, given the formula, I could calculate the percents for any value, such as 1.25 standard deviations from the mean.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality

Comment: @Galen That's not the origin.  The Empirical Rule merely uses a standard Normal distribution as a basis for comparison.  Jim: Welcome to our site.  Have you thought of [searching for the answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=68+95+99.7)?  Be a little wary: many of the posts about this rule assert that it's *only* for Normal distributions.  If that were the case it would be almost useless and wouldn't deserve the name "Empirical"!  It is an excellent **approximation** for many datasets provided they aren't hugely distorted compared to a Normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you w huber.  That solved my dilemma.